# socket.io - multiple browser windows

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I saw this code snippet which talks about how to group socket connections from the same user but in different windows:

```
sio.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.join(socket.handshake.sessionID);
});

app.get('/user/:id/:message', function (req, res) {
    sio.sockets.in(req.params.id).send(req.params.message);
});
```

I got this from this [blog post](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/).

How do I catch this sent message on the JS client side?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured this out. This is how we can catch the message on the client side:

```
socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);       
});
```